# removing vertices invalidates vertex properties in graph tool

Tags: graph-tool

I'm facing this little problem with graph-tool. I need to safely remove vertices with no in or out edges (with total degree==0 in practice), for this purpose I've written this little function

```
def clean(self):
        v_list = []
        for v in self.g.get_vertices():
            if self.g.get_out_degrees([v]) + self.g.get_in_degrees([v]) < 1:
                v_list.append(v)

        self.g.remove_vertex(v_list)
```

where `self.g` is a graph-tool `Graph` instance.

The problem is that the property map containing vertices' labels gets invalidated after this. However this seems to be a design choice, since it would be costly to reorganize the property map each time, as stated [here](https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/issues/82).

Therefore I was wondering how to save my labels. A solution I found is to filter out the vertices instead of deleting them

```
def clean(self):
        clean_map = self.g.new_vertex_property("bool")
        for v in self.g.get_vertices():
            if self.g.get_out_degrees([v]) + self.g.get_in_degrees([v]) < 1:
                clean_map[v] = False
            else:
                clean_map[v] = True

        self.g.set_vertex_filter(clean_map)
```

this doesn't invalidate the map anymore since the vertices don't get reordered, but it would be better to have vertices and labels map ordered for what I need to do afterwards.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing vertex or edges **DOES NOT** invalidate property maps in graph-tool.

Here's an example:

```
>>> g = Graph()                                                             
>>> g.add_vertex(10);                                                      
>>> p = g.vertex_index.copy()                                               
>>> p.fa                                                                    
PropertyArray([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> g.remove_vertex(5)                                                 
>>> p.fa                                                                    
PropertyArray([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

So there is no need to use filtering for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I don't understand why I'm facing the error then. I mean, I have this property map called `label2vertex` that associates a string (the label) to each vertex descriptor. At the beginning I have about 900 vertices but after cleaning they become 190, with indices reorganized in range 0-189, but my map still refers to previous descriptors. Indeed if I try to print `print(n, '-->', label, '-->', g.vertex_index[self.label2vertex[label]])` with n in `g.get_vertices()` I obtain different indices, for example `189 --> Ethanol --> 921
`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry just figured it out, `label2vertex` is not a property map, actually it is a separate dictionary I created for mapping labels into vertices. The property map I created is called `vertex2label`, the one that maps vertices into labels. This one should be updated after vertex deletion, right? So I only need to change my auxiliary dictionary starting from the updated property map I guess...